# G Suite: Can a Google Group be the owner of a folder in Drive?

Tags: google-drive-api, google-workspace

Can a Google Group be set as the *owner* of a folder in Drive?  Or is it the case that only single user accounts can be an owner of a folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The owner of a file can only be a single user, not a Group.

If you try to create a Permission on Drive API with `"role": "owner"` and `"type": "group"`, you will get the following error:

> Sorry, ownership can only be transferred to another user in the same domain as the current owner.

You can notice this too if you try to transfer ownership via UI (the option `Is owner` is not present for a Group).

That's because all members in a Group get the corresponding permission role of the Group, and you can't have multiple owners of a file.

#### Reference:

- [Permissions: create](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions/create)